Boundness of a convex function
Statement:
Let f:R->R such that f is convex and bounded then f is constant. .
Here is my proof :
Let f be a bounded convex function on R
Let  c, t be real numbers such that |t|≠0:
If t>0, then for any n belongs to natural such that n>c+t we have :
(f(c+t) -f(c)) /(t) < ((f(n) -f(c))/(n-c))
So,as f is bounded there exist M such that |f(x)|< M for all x.
Thus we have
|(f(c+t) -f(c)) /(t)|< 2M/(n-c)
If n goes to infinity
Then, f(c+t) =f(c) for all t>0
Similarly, one can very easily get the same result for t<0 . As c s any arbitrary real number, proving one part is sufficient.
Thus, we have our solution
Counter example:
If we did the same thing for e^(-x) in [0,inf) we will have that e^(-x) is constant.
So can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my proof and how the domain change is affecting.
Thanks for your help in advance

If the function is only defined on $[0, \infty)$ then you cannot “... easily get the same result for $t < 0$.”

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

@MartinR,  while considering the case of e^-x we don't have to do that, and if you are talking about the proof, then also we will have the same inequality
